# HTML <select> with element list

Tags: html, forms, variables, select, element

The following form  works exactly as expected, and provides a dropdown list to select an option from:

```
<select id="f-heroes" class="c-form-select__dropdown">
      <option value="" disabled selected>Heroes</option>
      <option value="captainAmerica">Captain America</option>
      <option value="ironMan">Iron Man</option>
      <option value="blackWidow">Black Widow</option>
      <option value="thor">Thor</option>
</select>
```

What I am trying to do is this:

```
<select id="f-heroes" class="c-form-select__dropdown">
      <option value=""><?echo getElement('hero');?></option>         
</select>
```

This gets the 'hero' list but displays it below and out of the option window, and leaves me no option to select a value.

I may be missing something really simple here, but can't seem to get this to work, any help much appreciated.

Comment: Can you define the getElement() function?

Comment: If getElement(...) returns a list, you can't just echo it inside a single <option> and expect it to come out right. What does the resulting HTML (i.e. the browser source) look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your mixing PHP and JavaScript here. From my understanding of your question, you're wanting to create a loop that keeps creating 's for each of your superheroes.

If that's correct, you could use PHP and do something like the below:

```
<select id="f-heroes" class="c-form-select__dropdown">
<option value="" disabled selected>Heroes</option>
<?php
$superHeroes = array('Captain America','Iron Man','Black Widow','Thor');
$i = 0;
while ($i < count($superHeroes)) {
   $name = $superHeroes[$i];
   echo "<option value='".$name."'>".$name."</option>";
   $i++;
}?>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks @Pete Boucher this does what I need it to do, just slightly different from the way the other pages have been set up by colleagues. Can definitely use this, though, thanks again.